# Moving child node to parent level using XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML with child nodes which I want them to appear in parent level node using XSL. My XML is not very simple and my knowledge of XSL is not very good.
I will be great if any one can provide me a solution.

My Sample XML is as follows:

```
<env:Envelope
  xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  <env:Body>
    <DPSretrieveResponse
      xmlns="https://tpvs.hmrc.gov.uk/dps">
      <DPSdata
        xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/DPSwrapper/1">
        <DPSheader>
          <Service>PAYE</Service>
          <EntityType>EmpRef</EntityType>          
        </DPSheader>        
        <CodingNoticesP6P6B FormType="P6B" IssueDate="2008-05-06" SequenceNumber="1375" TaxYearEnd="2009"
          xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/CodingNoticesP6P6B/2">
          <EmployerRef>123/A6</EmployerRef>
          <Name>
            <Title>MR</Title>
            <Forename>J V</Forename>
            <Surname>Scanlon</Surname>
          </Name>
          <WorksNumber>SCA/466</WorksNumber>
          <CodingUpdate>
            <TaxCode>NT</TaxCode>
          </CodingUpdate>
        </CodingNoticesP6P6B>
        </DPSdata>
    </DPSretrieveResponse>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

What I require is:

```
<env:Envelope
  xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <env:Body>
    <DPSretrieveResponse
      xmlns="https://tpvs.hmrc.gov.uk/dps">
      <DPSdata
        xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/DPSwrapper/1">
        <DPSheader>
          <Service>PAYE</Service>
          <EntityType>EmpRef</EntityType>          
        </DPSheader>        
        <CodingNoticesP6P6B FormType="P6B" IssueDate="2008-05-06" SequenceNumber="1375" TaxYearEnd="2009"
          xmlns="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/CodingNoticesP6P6B/2">
          <EmployerRef>123/A6</EmployerRef>
          <Name>          
          </Name>
          <Title>MR</Title>
          <Forename>J V</Forename>
          <Surname>Scanlon</Surname>
          <WorksNumber>SCA/466</WorksNumber>
          <CodingUpdate>
            <TaxCode>NT</TaxCode>
          </CodingUpdate>
        </CodingNoticesP6P6B>
        </DPSdata>
    </DPSretrieveResponse>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Simply, Title, Forename and Surname under Name tag need to be displayed in the same level as Name;

```
<Name>          
</Name>
<Title>MR</Title>
<Forename>J V</Forename>
<Surname>Scanlon</Surname>
```

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how does the output you're getting now differ from what you require?  Could you edit the question to show your current XSLT?

Comment: If you have one identity template (to copy all nodes), create a second one that selects the `Name` element (possibly prefixing it with the appropriate namespace) containing just  `<xsl:apply-templates />`. It will move the children of  `Name` to the place where the `Name` element was before.

Comment: Also, we need to know what _version_ of XSLT you're using.  Do you have access to 2.0 or later, or are you restricted to 1.0 only?

Answer (score 0):

With an identity template you copy all nodes that shouldn't change in the result tree:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You can create a separate template for the root node to add the extra namespace declarations:

```
<xsl:template match="env:Envelope">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:namespace name="xsi" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'" />
        <xsl:namespace name="soapenc" select="'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'" />
        <xsl:namespace name="xsd" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Finally, to move the children of `Name` up one level, first you need to declare the namespace where `Name` belongs to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 ... xmlns:ns0="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/CodingNoticesP6P6B/2">
```

so you can qualify the match with the prefix you declared. Then you just call `<apply-templates/>` on the children without copying the current element:

```
<xsl:template match="ns0:Name">
     <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Here is a full stylesheet which should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns0="http://www.govtalk.gov.uk/taxation/CodingNoticesP6P6B/2"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns0"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="env:Envelope">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:namespace name="xsi" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'" />
            <xsl:namespace name="soapenc" select="'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'" />
            <xsl:namespace name="xsd" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns0:Name">
         <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```